# When validating an item in a workflow action, null reference error?

Tags: workflow, validation

So, I have an item with a couple of fields that have required `validation rules`.

I've added a validation action when executing a `workflow` action (submitting to admin for approval).  When I do this a modal comes up that shows the fields and whether they have validated.

When I intentionally leave the `required fields` blank, it flags them as being required.  However, in addition to this, under the "Item" section, there's a row that has "`Is rendered item valid XHTML document.The item must render as a valid XHTML document.`" in the left column, and in the right column it says:

> An error occurred while validating: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`"

instead of OK.

I'm wondering what it's tripping up on and how to get rid of this so as not to confuse users?  When I fill the required fields in, I can execute the `workflow` action successfully.

Comment: Is this helpful https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/941511 ?

Comment: @Levi Wallach, this issue is fixed?

Comment: @AbhishekMalaviya, yes, sorry, the second approach below worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Marek Musielak.

You can fix this issue with below approaches:

### First Approach

There is no validation schema for `HTML5` available yet. However, it is possible to extend the current `XSD` schema that Sitecore uses for XHTML validation to allow some of the `HTML5` tags. The original schema file is located and specified in the `XHtmlSchemaFile` setting in web.config:

```
<setting name="XHtmlSchemaFile" value="/sitecore/shell/schemas/sitecore xhtml.xsd" />
```

For example,  to allow the  tag, you should modify the schema file as follows:

Create a new `xs:element` node under the root node for the `<article>` tag:

```
<xs:element name="article">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="block" />
        <xs:group ref="inline" />
        <xs:group ref="misc" />
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="coreattrs" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Add the newly created element definition to the group of block elements:

```
<xs:group name="block">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element ref="p" />
      <xs:group ref="heading" />
      <xs:element ref="div" />
      <xs:group ref="lists" />
      <xs:group ref="blocktext" />
      <xs:element ref="fieldset" />
      <xs:element ref="table" />
      <xs:element ref="article" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>
```

### Second Approach

Alternatively, it is possible to disable XHTML validation so that items with HTML5 markup can be approved in a workflow. To do this, **remove** Full Page XHtml and `Is Xhtml` rules from the **Workflow field** of the following items:

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Types/Rich Text
```

[image]

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Global Rules
```

[image]

**Reference:** https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/941511

Answer (score -1):

You can get rid of XHTML validation by:

1. Navigate to /sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Types/YourFieldType
2. Go to the Workflow field under "Validation Rules" and deselect the Is Xhtml rule. 
   [image]

Comment: I'm not a fan of this approach because it modifies default templates and could be overridden by an upgrade.